# Determining the difference between new Object and new fn

Tags: javascript, prototype

How do you determine the difference between `new Object` and `new fn` under these conditions?

- `var fn = function(){};`
- `fn.prototype = {};`
- You may not rely on `__proto__` or `Object.getPrototypeOf` existing, as they are not in IE or Opera.
- The solution may not statically use `fn`, such as `instanceof fn`.
- Implementing your own `Object.getPrototypeOf` is fine.

**Not required:** It would be nice if your solution works with objects from other frames and doesn't use function serialization.

Here's some example base code to start off with:

```
var fn = function(){};
fn.prototype = {};

var x = new fn,
y = new Object;

fn = null; // prohibit static reference to fn

// define your detection function here
function isNewObject(obj) {

};

alert(isNewObject(x) !== isNewObject(y) ? "pass" : "fail");
```

Comment: You mean you want to know whether foo is an instance of SomeClass, or just an Object with the same properties?

Comment: I don't think this is possible.

Comment: @gs It _is_ possible with __proto__ or Object.getPrototypeOf but that's obviously not cross-browser.

Comment: I mean it is possible with `__proto__` or `Object.getPrototypeOf`.

Comment: The question has already stated this.

Comment: Yeah seems like it's not going to be possible to do this. I'm a bit curious why you can't just use instanceof though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you can't do this in ES3 with only standard support, and here's why:

Look at `x` and `y` creation.

```
var fn = function(){};
fn.prototype = {};

var x = new fn,
    y = new Object;
```

When `x` is instantiated, its internal [[Prototype]] is being set to an object referenced by `fn.prototype` (just an `Object` object that you assigned to `fn.prototype`). Object's constructor - `fn` - is then being called in a context of that newly created object, but since it doesn't mutate ab object in any way, we can consider that step irrelevant.

When `y` is instantiated, its internal [[Prototype]] is being set to `Object.prototype`, which is an `Object` object too. Its constructor (`Object`) is then being called in a context of this newly created object as well, but nothing happens there either.

So now you end up with 2 `Object` objects which only differ in that their internal [[Prototype]]'s reference different objects - `x`'s one references whatever you assigned to `fn.prototype` and `y`'s references `Object.prototype`. Their internal [[Class]] properties are identical too (i.e. equal to "Object")

You can't get direct access to [[Prototype]] in ES3. You can infer something about it by using `instanceof`, but since `fn` is nulled in your example `intanceof`-based inference is out of the picture.

Now, you can augment `Object` constructor in such way that it would somehow mutate instantiated object. You can then inspect an object and detect this augmentation. For example:

```
Object = function() {
  return ({ __: void 0 });
}
```

and then:

```
function isNewObject(object) {
  return '__' in object;
}
```

but this will, of course, only work when object is being created with `new Object` and not via, say, an object literal - `{ }`. It's also rather obtrusive :)

Perhaps there are other ways, but I can't see them right now.

HTH

Comment: Your solution would only work if someone doesn't explicitly define `__', but it's seems the only possible way (other than bruteforcing by iterating over properties and using !obj.hasOwnProperty(..) and !Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty(..))

Comment: You can always change "__" to a more unique token, of course, but the problem would still persist. Any script would be able to spoof Object object by adding/deleting this unique token.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know your problem is impossible to solve with ES3: `instanceof` and `isPrototypeOf()` can't be used to solve it because the prototype object of `fn` is inaccessible, and only ES5 allows access to the internal [[Prototype]] property via `Object.getPrototypeOf()`.

Btw, an even harder problem to solve would be if you assign `Object.prototype` to `fn.prototype`, eg

```
var x = (function() {
    function Foo() {}
    Foo.prototype = Object.prototype;
    return new Foo;
})();
```

As the prototype chain of `Foo` and `Object` instances is identical, there shouldn't be any way to distinguish them.